# SQL - SELECT from table B only if table A is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a primary table FXTB which contains columns; currency, rate, date(today's date only).

I want to generate ONE! SQL to select from table FXTB but if I provide it an older date (which would return nothing from FXTB, it will select from another table called FXTBHistory
with the same column names but containing data for different dates.

Please let me know if it is not clear enough.

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter answer is the correct one, you only have to do a UNION, whether any of the table is null, it will return all the data, providing the 2 tables holds the same table schema!

Comment: the issue is with the rates values... the smallest decimal difference will result in duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the approaches using `union`, in this constellation a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is also possible. The `ifnull` will return the `FXTB` values, and only if they are `null`, the `FXTBHistory` values will be returned:

```
SELECT ifnull(FXTB.currency, FXTBHistory.currency) as currency,
       ifnull(FXTB.rate, FXTBHistory.rate) as rate, 
       ifnull(FXTB.date, FXTBHistory.date) as date
FROM FXTBHistory LEFT OUTER JOIN FXTB
  ON FXTBHistory.currency = FXTB.currency
  AND FXTBHistory.date = FXTB.date
  WHERE ifnull(FXTB.date, FXTBHistory.date) = @date
UNION
SELECT ifnull(FXTB.currency, FXTBHistory.currency) as currency,
       ifnull(FXTB.rate, FXTBHistory.rate) as rate, 
       ifnull(FXTB.date, FXTBHistory.date) as date
FROM FXTBHistory RIGHT OUTER JOIN FXTB
  ON FXTBHistory.currency = FXTB.currency
  AND FXTBHistory.date = FXTB.date
  WHERE ifnull(FXTB.date, FXTBHistory.date) = @date;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c97e23/6 to see it in action.

Comment: Actually, the left outer join is not enough if your history table does not contain a record for today but the fxtb table does. I have updated my answer with a better solution.

Comment: This looks much better... but what if both queries brought results... ? for most of the currencies the rates might be the same, but there can be minor decimal differences potentially, would that result in duplicate rows for the same currency?

Comment: I will work with this query more...and probably accpet this answer tomorrow...if it made total sense to me. It is just that getting duplicate values will fail my whole process.

Comment: In the case that both tables have a result, both queries will return the fxtb data which will get unified to one row by the union. (Note that I removed the currency from the join conditions). If only one table has a row for the date, then only one of the queries will return a row. Not that this query assumes at most one row with the same date and currency in FXTBHistory. If there are multiple rows for a date and currency, but no row in FXTB, then all rows for that date and currency will be returned.

Comment: if I can use the dataset from either table A or B, not a mix of both (if currency doesn't exist in one)... also what happens if they do not get unified because a small decimal difference ?

Comment: I don't join the rate columns, so no decimal differences.

Answer (score 4):

Do a UNION

```
SELECT currency, rate, date FROM FXTB WHERE date = @date
UNION
SELECT currency, rate, date FROM FXTBHistory WHERE date = @date
```

If the first result is empty - second will provide the result. If for some reason there're duplicate entries between 2 results - UNION will eliminate the duplicates

In case you receive not quite duplicates (different rate, for the same date according your comments), but you're interested in getting on record only - you can try something like this (not tested)

```
WITH FXTBAll AS
    (SELECT currency, rate, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY currency, date ORDER BY currency, date) RN FROM 
        (SELECT currency, rate, date FROM FXTB WHERE date = @date
        UNION
        SELECT currency, rate, date FROM FXTBHistory WHERE date = @date) T
    )
SELECT currency, rate, date FROM FXTBAll WHERE RN = 1
```

It still uses the same UNION, but builts a CTE on top of it and using ROW_NUMBER() for partitioning selects 1st record for every group

Comment: The issue with UNION is that it returns duplicate values, if the data exist in both tables but rate value has a decimal point difference.

Comment: @Achilles, it sounds like the data is moved to `FXTBHistory` from `FXTB`, so there shouldn't be dups.

Comment: @Achilles so, currency, and date is the same in both tables, only rate is different? you can have different rate from the same date from 2 tables?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes both tables might have the same date/currency/ but rate could be fractionally different.

Comment: @Achilles in this case what rate are u interested in? Considering that everything else is the same?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I am always interested in FXTB !!! but if I am using a previous date then FXTBHistory table...

Comment: So FXTB will not have previous date? Only FXTBHistory  will? Or any date can be in any table? Not sure I understand your data setup

Comment: No FXTB will only have today's data. FXTBHistory can have today and previous dates data... if both tables have the data... this does not mean rates are identical. If the rates are not identical, it will result in UNION outputing duplivates

Answer (score 2):

**If you want records from FXTBHistory only if no records exist in FXTB *for any currency* on @date:**

```
SELECT currency, rate, date
FROM FXTB
WHERE date = @date
UNION ALL
SELECT currency, rate, date
FROM FXTBHistory
WHERE date = @date
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FXTB WHERE date = @date)
```

**If you want to pick between FXTB and FXTBHistory on a currency-by-currency basis:**

```
SELECT
 @date                                AS date,
 COALESCE(new.currency, old.currency) AS currency,
 COALESCE(new.rate    , old.rate)     AS rate
FROM FXTB new
FULL JOIN FXTBHistory old ON (
  new.currency = old.currency AND
  new.date     = old.date
)
WHERE new.date = @date
  OR  old.date = @date
```